# Is it a good idea to have frontend app share session on subdomain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, reactjs

I'm working on breaking out a piece of my company's codebase (a monolithic Rails app) into a separate React application that communicates with the main application's API.

Originally, I was going to authorize requests with JSON web tokens. But then I realized that you can set up Rails apps to share sessions. So I put the React app inside of a Rails app that has no DB and configured it and the main app to share their sessions. The main app redirects users to this app living on a subdomain, and I don't have to worry about complicated login logic because the sessions are shared.

I'm curious if there are any drawbacks or reasons why this wouldn't be a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

My humble feedback on this topic would be to attempt to intelligently, and of your own understanding, answer the below questions and see how you feel about those answers.

1. what does rails add to the process of session management? ie, encrypting the cookie and verification of that cookie.
2. how strong does this process 'seem' to you?
3. how could the process be exploited and or negatively manipulated in a subdomain like environment?
4. how much does exploitation matter (ie, sensitive financial data on an application at scale or a potential throw away prototype to learn about something)

JD